# Convert a Urban Dictionary definition into a list where each item is set to max length

Tags: python, api, discord.py

I want to send Urban Dictionary definitions on discord, but sometimes the definitions are longer than 1024 characters, which is the max length.

What I want: If the definition is longer than 1024 characters, split the definitions into a list with the first item being 1024 and the other items rest of the definition. If the other item is also longer than 1024 characters, repeat the process. Here is what I got so far:

```
    async def _urbandictionary(self, ctx, *, term):
    url = "https://mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com/define"
    querystring = {"term":term}
    headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "mashape-community-urban-dictionary.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "key"
    }
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring) as response:
            r = await response.json()
            definition = r['list'][0]['definition']
            example = r['list'][0]['example']
            if len(definition) >= 1024:
                split_number = int(len(definition) / 1024) + 1 
            result_list=[definition[y-split_number:y] for y in range(split_number, len(definition)+split_number,split_number)]
            embed = discord.Embed(title=term, description="First definition found:") # <- [1]
            await ctx.send(embed=embed) # <- This sends the embed into discord. 
            num = 1
            for i in result_list:
                em = discord.Embed(title=" ", description = " ")
                em.add_field(name=f"{num}/{split_number}", value=i, inline = False) # <- [2]
                await ctx.send(embed=em)
                num += 1
```

If you are not familiar with the discord.py library, read the TL:DR definition below. Embed basically makes the text pretty.

[1] This is creating the embed. There has to be a title and a description

[2] This is an add_field function. From the name you can see that it add's a field. That's basically everything.

I know this is wrong. The length checker is correct, but creating of the result_list isn't. I found it online and tried it, only to realize that this splits string into lists with desired lenght per item in list.

What can I try in order for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works for me.

```
result_list = [definition]

while len(result_list[-1]) > 1024:
    firstPart = result_list[-1][:1024]
    secondPart = result_list[-1][1024:]

    result_list[-1] = firstPart
    result_list.append(secondPart)
```